# pure css hover show another element possible?

Tags: html, css

```
<a href="">
  text here always show
 <div  style="display:none;">
   hide text here
 </div>
</a>


a:hover{

//when hover show 'hide text here' ; when not hover, hide it again 
}
```

possible to use pure css to do this effect?

Comment: Just a note - you shouldn't nest the `<div>` since it is a block level element and the `<a>` is inline level.  Change the `<div>` to a `<span>` and your HTML will validate.

Comment: @Pat Block level links are [allowed in HTML5](http://html5doctor.com/block-level-links-in-html-5/).

Answer (score 49, accepted):

```
a div {
    display: none;
}

a:hover div {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: How can a `display:none` element hovered?

Comment: @Harikrishnan A `display: none` element can't be hovered.  Why do you ask?

Comment: First `a` is `none` in your `CSS`, then how can it be hovered?

Comment: @Harikrishnan `a` is not not `display: none` in my CSS

Comment: i did not understand your CSS that is why i asked

Comment: @Harikrishnan `a div {}` as a CSS selector selects `div`s that are children of `a`s.