# CSS selector for :hover plus no mouse-button pressed?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-ui, stylesheet

I am currently using `:hover`CSS pseudo-class for displaying tooltip-like elements (i.e. `table`s) in a way similar to what is suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6305190/1789384):

```
div.tool:hover div.tooltip { display:block; }
```

I like the fact that this does not require any JavaScript.

Is it possible to add a further constraint to the effect that the hover only applies if no mouse button is pressed? The reason is that I want to prevent interference of these tooltips with other functionality (drag-and-drop, drop-down menus) that is based on jQuery UI. (As it happens, the tooltips are currently dragged together with their corresponding "tool" elements.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically the if mouse clicked css selector method id :active so what you would have to do is this:

```
.tool {
    min-height: 18px;
    height: auto;
}
.tool:active .tooltip {
    display: none !important;
}
.tool:hover .tooltip {
    display: block;
}
.tooltip {
    display: none;
}
```

The order is crucial because the higher rules take priority

Here is a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Hive7/bsnnb6sf/

Also you might want to consider using visibility instead of display because otherwise you need to set the height of the parent:

```
.tool:active .tooltip {
    visibility: hidden !important;
}
.tool:hover .tooltip {
    visibility: visible;
}
.tooltip {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Hive7/bsnnb6sf/1/

Comment: This does only work for the currently dragged element. Other elements still get the hover event, and because they are not active, will show the tooltip.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to add a further constraint to the effect that the
>   hover only applies if no mouse button is pressed?

One option could be to use [`:active`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:active) pseudo-class to hide the tooltip. According to the spec: *(my emphasis)*

> **[5.11.3 The dynamic pseudo-classes: :hover, :active, and :focus](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#dynamic-pseudo-classes)**
>
> The `:active` pseudo-class applies while an element is being activated
>   by the user. For example, **between the times the user presses the mouse
>   button and releases it**.

For instance:

```css
div.tool:hover  div.tooltip { display:block; }
div.tool:active div.tooltip { display:none; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that's not possible because the hover event will always launch before the click event. If you want to disable that effect once the user clicks the element, you could add custom style rules to the css in the click event overriding the hover rules via `element.addClass()` or `element.css()`

Comment: it is possible look at my answer