# Label Hide/Show when mousing over an image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseover, image

I am trying to have a label being shown when the user mouse over the image

For example, if the user mouseover Image1, it would hide label 2 & 3 but show label 1. I do know how to change text when mouseover, but I don't know how to do this.

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
    div#line1 span#a {
        display:inline;
    }
    div#line1:hover span#a {
        display:none;
    }
    div#line1 span#b {
        display:none;
    }
    div#line1:hover span#b {
        display:inline;
    }
</style>

</head>
<body>
<div id="line1">
    <table border="1">
        <tr>  
            <td>
                <span id="a">this is sick</span><span id="b">this is awesome</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You tagged your question with JavaScript and jQuery yet I see none. Are you looking for a JavaScript solution or CSS only?

Comment: I am sure there are many examples of this which can be found by searching.

Comment: For a [css solution...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3659294/pure-css-hover-show-another-element-possible)

Answer (score 2):

Change this:

```
div#line1:hover span#b {
    display:inline;
}
```

to:

```
div#line1:hover > span#b {
    display:inline;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/hwxfV/

Comment: I haven't used this one before 1up for this because any time I needed to make hover effect affect a separate object, I have always gone for a javascript solution.

Answer (score 0):

JQuery would be an easy way to show/hide whatever you want in an event.

```
$("#image1").hover(function(){
  //hover handler
  $("#label1, #label2").css("display", "none");
}.
function(){
  //un-hover handler
  $("#label1, #label2").css("display", "block");
});
```