# Revealing text on hover image

Tags: javascript, css, image, text, hover

With my code, i am using a script that generates a random set of 4 images that gets displayed on refresh. I wish to only display the text when the cursor is hovering over the respective image.

Any pointers on doing this with CSS? I am not sure where to put the hover element. http://jsfiddle.net/sugarcraving/Af72K/1/

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".champ").hide();

var elements = $(".champ");
var elementCount = elements.size();
var elementsToShow = 4;
var alreadyChoosen = ",";
var i = 0;
while (i < elementsToShow) {
    var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * elementCount);
    if (alreadyChoosen.indexOf("," + rand + ",") < 0) {
        alreadyChoosen += rand + ",";
        elements.eq(rand).show();
        ++i;
    }
}
});
```

CSS

```
div.champ { 
display: none; 
float: left;
color: red;
}
```

Comment: You can refer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3659294/pure-css-hover-show-another-element-possible) which seems pretty close to what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following what Rouse02 said, add something around the context you want to hide/show.

```
<p>Celebi, the 251</p>
```

Then in your css, hide the content and only show it when you hover on the div (you could do it on the image hover as well).

```
p {
    visibility:hidden;
}
.champ:hover p {
    visibility:visible;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/bzTnR/1/

Answer (score 0):

```
div.champ: hover{
    visibility: hidden;
}
div.champ: hover p{
    visibility: visible 
}
```

Where p is the element within your div that holds the text.

Hope this helps.

V/R

Comment: That doesn't seem to work. I think the problem is the use of an image tag? http://jsfiddle.net/sugarcraving/5raR3/

Comment: oops, I forgot to hide the `<p>` first. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could help! Let me know if this wasn't you were looking for

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Af72K/6/)

I changed CSS to like this : `div.text{display:none} div.champ:hover div.text{display:block}`

Answer (score 0):

i've updated your fiddle..here..try this

`div.champ p{
    visibility: hidden;
}`

`div.champ:hover p{
    visibility: visible;
}`

[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5raR3/1/)